# Look for first cell that's <> NA then return average of an array starting with first data point

Tags: excel

I need to search a column, starting from the bottom and going up. I want the formula to search for the first cell with a value (1-4 cells might have NA before the data starts, see image) and then return the average of six cells. Then I'd also like to do the same thing but skip the first cell with a value and take the average of the six cells after that first cell.

[Data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ETA9D.png)

[image]

Comment: `and then return the average of 6 cells.`   Do you mean... average the LAST six cells directly above the FIRST NA in a column? And which column?

Comment: The average of the 6 cells above the last NA. in most cases there's only one NA but there might be 2-3 cells that read NA and I'd like it to pick the first cell with data and start the average of 6 cells from there. I'd like to return this average for each column.

Comment: Will there ALWAYS be at least six cells with number above the NA in question?

Comment: Yes, it's monthly economic data going back 10 or more years

Comment: One final question... Is it possible that there can be an NA further up the column than the NA in question ?

Comment: OK. So another way to phrase the NA in question is that it is the first one in the column from the TOP  ?

Comment: Sorry I'm not sure I understand the question? Right now we want to start from the bottom but we may invert the data. there's dates in column A and the most recent data is at the bottom and we're looking for the most recent data.

Comment: Understood that the data to average are the last six NUMBERS in the column. I'm just asking about the NA directly below these numbers. It is the FIRST NA when looking from the top of the column downward, right?

Comment: well if looking from the top downwards then the first number after the NAs end. so if  it's NA,1,2,3,4,5,6,... or NA,NA,NA,1,2,3,4,5,6,.... then it should yield the same thing. look down the columm and pick up the first value (1) then start the average of 6 cells. I'll try your answer and see if it works for all.

Comment: I believe the answer I have posted will work only for the scenario you initially described where the data to average are at the bottom with the NA's after that.

Comment: It doesn't seem to work. Is it better if I invert the data and start from the top?

Comment: Any chance you can send me a small sample worksheet? I'll sort it out quickly. My email address is:  daniel.ferry@gmail.com

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand correctly, this will give the average of the last six numbers in column B:

```
=AVERAGE(OFFSET(B1,MATCH("NA",B:B,)-7,,6))
```

Just change the B's for other columns.